# Able to access non-secure LDAP over port 636

Tags: windows, active-directory, ldap

I have enabled LDAPS in my Windows AD environment. Using LDP.exe, I am able to connect to the server in question on port 636 with the SSL option both checked and unchecked. Does that mean that plaintext is being passed over port 636 with the option unchecked? Is it possible to force the server to listen for SSL traffic only on port 636?

SSL Unchecked:

```
ld = ldap_open("server.domain.com", 636);
Established connection to server.domain.com.
Retrieving base DSA information...
Getting 1 entries:
Dn: (RootDSE)
```

SSL Checked:

```
ld = ldap_sslinit("server.domain.com", 636, 1);
Error 0 = ldap_set_option(hLdap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
Error 0 = ldap_connect(hLdap, NULL);
Error 0 = ldap_get_option(hLdap,LDAP_OPT_SSL,(void*)&lv);
Host supports SSL, SSL cipher strength = 128 bits
Established connection to server.domain.com.
Retrieving base DSA information...
Getting 1 entries:
Dn: (RootDSE)
```

Comment: After running some Wireshark traces, it appears that the data is encrypted regardless if the SSL box is checked. I would still be interested to hear from anyone who may have some insight about this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That checkbox exists.for the scenario where the service may be on a non-default port.  It does not enable the client to override server encryption settings/requirements.